# Firefox 57+ Network Response HTML Preview

Tags: firefox

on Firefox 57 "Network analysis" I miss the preview of the answer I got.

For example, an Ajax is sent and you get an answer directly as text / code. That is a good thing.
See "Response" (In image "Antwort" on the right side)

What I'm missing is that I can toggle to a preview to see what the content looks like.

Apparently another tab should come automatically, with content type (type) html, with which I can change then. That has never happened.

Can you help me?

[image: Firefox Debugger Tools Network monitor analysis]

Answer (score -1):

The preview pane has been removed from the Response details in Firefox 55 (see [bug report #1350229](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1350229)), so it's not possible right now.

Good news though, it will be back in the Response side panel in Firefox 59, according to [bug report #1353319](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1353319).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I edited my answer to include all necessary information. The links are just references to the bug reports.